# Reading and writing to/from csv files

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I want my program to read 2 columns (the first and the second one) and add them to an array. They are dependent on eachother - so they need to be written alongside eachother, as in the first row (both columns) next to eachother, and then the second row and so on.

I have managed to write the first column (containing the names) to the array, however have not managed to write the second column to the array.

```
rownum=1
array=[]
for row in reader:
    if row[1] != '' and row[1] != 'Score':
        array.append(row[1])
        rownum=rownum+1
        if rownum==11:
            break
```

I attempted to append more than one row however it returns the error message 'only accepts one argument'.
Any ideas how I can do this so i can reference the score for each name from the csv file

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
d = {} #curly braces denote an empty dictionary
for row in reader:
    d[row[0]] = row[1]
```

`d`, in this case, would be a dictionary with the first column of your csv file as the keys and the second column as the corresponding values.

You can access it very similar to how you access a list. Say you had `Brian,80` as one of the entries in your csv file, `d["Brian"]` would return `80`.

**EDIT**

OP has requested (in the comments) for a more complete version of the code. Assuming OP's code already works, I'll modify that code so it works with a dictionary:

```
rownum=1
d={} #denotes an empty dictionary
for row in reader:
    if row[1] != '' and row[1] != 'Score':
        d[row[0]]=row[1] #first column is the key/index, second column is the value
        rownum=rownum+1
        if rownum==11:
            break
```

Comment: The assumption in this answer is that the keys are unique and there are no duplicate rows.

Comment: Could you please add more detail and show what the finished code looks like? I have played around with this and cannot get the code to work.

Comment: @jpp Yes, thank you for mentioning that.
CallumTwig I have edited the answer per your request. Please inform me if it works.